# Isolated nodes appearing in the network in R

Tags: r, graph

I am using library(network) and have the following edge list to generate a network.

Commands used:

```
library(network)
edgelist<-read.table("Filename")
net<-network(edgelist)
plot(net)
```

what I observe is isolated nodes in the network plot! Can anyone help in deciphering the reason?? I used the same edgelist with Cytoscape. It works perfect there. Why is it causing problem in R?
[image]

Following is the edgelist:

```
7   2  
2   6  
3   2  
13  2  
1   2  
4   2  
5   2  
9   2  
25  29  
5   4  
13  8  
18  17  
5   15  
13  1  
22  8  
25  12  
21  11  
17  28  
18  8  
13  16  
33  20  
10  27  
12  4  
24  23  
12  1  
19  26  
4   3  
3   15  
8   11  
16  62  
36  8  
18  11  
10  62  
4   6  
4   1  
32  62  
12  16  
4   15  
17  30  
22  10  
34  11  
31  10  
9   6  
4   7  
24  20  
5   6  
1   6  
3   6  
9   7  
21  19  
35  23  
7   6  
10  8  
5   7  
1   7  
3   7  
1   3  
1   9  
5   1  
3   9  
5   3  
5   9
```

Comment: You can start by labelling vertices to see which may not have at least a pair.

Comment: Labelled them, but it shows every single vertex as an isolated node (which s clearly not the case even in the edge list)

Comment: Found the reason! R network library requires node IDs to be in sequential order. One of the IDs was 62, while there was no node with an ID between 36 and 62. It ended up isolating those IDs as vertices..Once that problem was fixed, it worked well.

Comment: Consider posting the solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason! R network library requires node IDs to be in sequential order. One of the IDs was 62, while there was no node with an ID between 36 and 62. It ended up isolating those IDs as vertices..Once that problem was fixed, it worked well.